# How to validate an iOS consumable in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store

When a user purchases a consumable, my `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` receives an array of `SKPaymentTransaction`. The app can then check the `transaction.TransactionState` and `transaction.Payment.ProductIdentifier` to verify that the iap has actually been purchased.

But my app uses that in order to allow the user to download content from my web service. So the question is how can **the web service** validate  that the app has actually purchased the iap, and not that it's a fake app just saying it did? I need some way to validate the `SKPaymentTransaction` *on the server*. Either by a signature, or by an app-store verification-service.

[Windows has a way to do this on UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases)  . Is there a way to do this on iOS?

I've checked [SKPaymentTransaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransaction)  , [SKPayment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpayment)  , etc. but all either don't show a way for validation, or they're about non-consumables (which are kept in the app's receipt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to validate an iOS consumable in-app purchase.

Firstly, You can validate the receipt locally in the app[(see Validating Receipts Locally)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2) . However, it is still susceptible to cracking.

The safest way is to perform server-side validation by sending the receipt to your server then sending it on to Apple [(see Validating Receipts With the App Store)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1).